# Set $default route in API gateway for REST APIs

Tags: rest, routes, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have some REST APIs my backend server listens for (I used node express).
I want to use my friendly url `api.mywebsite.com` to forward all routes to `horribleuglybackendname.aws.com`, e.g.
`api.mywebsite.com/some/route` -> `horribleuglybackendname.aws.com/some/route`

I want to use API gateway to simply forward any routes to my backend. If I create a HTTP API (not REST) this seems easy to do but if I create a REST API I cannot see how to configure it. Perhaps you can't? If you can't why not? What is the alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So it seems `$default` is for HTTP APIs only. The UI is different between HTTP and REST API configuration. If you want to do a catch-all route for REST APIs you need to use {proxy+}.

This is good (ctrl-f for catch-all and you should be set)
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/